# how do i embed Klaviyo pop-up form into my React app

Tags: reactjs, embed

I am stumped, I thought this was straightforward embeds but it doesn't seem so?

I was given these 2 bits of info after I created a pop-up form in Klaviyo.

1. `<div class=“klaviyo-form-FORMID”></div>`

I am trying to have this buttonImage.png onClick render the Klaviyo form div from my React Component.

Can anyone assist??

here is the trigger:

```
       <ReactComponent>
          <div className="klaviyo-form-FORMID">
            <img className="buttonImage" src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/ButtonImage.png"} onClick={() => { 
//2.
              window._klForms = window._klForms || []; 
              window._klForms.push('FORMID');
              window._klOnsite = window._klOnsite || []; 
              window._klOnsite.push(['openForm', 'FORMID']);
            }} />
//
          </div>
          </ReactComponent>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to integrate Klaviyo with my NextJS app. My issue was that I forgot to attach a script to the wrapper of the button as instructed here https://help.klaviyo.com/hc/en-us/articles/5486899706267.

so in your case it will be:

```
  // I use useEffect here but this can be appended in the head from the _app.jsx or _document.jsx or call this window.onLoad
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = `https://static.klaviyo.com/onsite/js/klaviyo.js?company_id={PUBLIC_API_KEY}`;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(script);
  }, []);


<ReactComponent>
       <div class=container>
          <div className="klaviyo-form-FORMID">
            <img className="buttonImage" src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/ButtonImage.png"} onClick={() => { 
              window._klForms = window._klForms || []; 
              window._klForms.push('FORMID');
              window._klOnsite = window._klOnsite || []; 
              window._klOnsite.push(['openForm', 'FORMID']);
            }} />
          </div>
      </div>
 </ReactComponent>
```